# How to update a document’s field in firestore?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to update a field in a firestore document without fetching the entire document. Can someone help me ?

Comment: The documentation gives examples of how to update a document, but since you didn't say what kind of update you're doing, it's not really possible to say if you can avoid fetching the document first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firestore documentation shows this example of updating a field in a document:

> ```
> var washingtonRef = db.collection("cities").doc("DC");
>
> // Set the "capital" field of the city 'DC'
> return washingtonRef.update({
>     capital: true
> })
> .then(function() {
>     console.log("Document successfully updated!");
> })
> .catch(function(error) {
>     // The document probably doesn't exist.
>     console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
> });
> ```

As you'll note, this code does not load the document initially. To be able to do this, you must know the ID of the document you want to update (`"DC"` in the above sample code).